# Fetching image from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I'm fetching images from Dropbox using following Java code:

```
private void downloadFile(@NonNull final String inPath, @NonNull final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, DbxException {
    mClient.files().downloadBuilder(inPath).download(outputStream);
}
```

This code works correctly! However, we need to wait for entire JPG to download before it can be shown.
However, is it possible to display partial images as soon as they are fetched using Dropbox?
using Dropbox version 3.0.3

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use the [`DbxDownloadStyleBuilder.start`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxDownloadStyleBuilder.html#start--) pattern with [`getInputStream`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxDownloader.html#getInputStream--) instead.